# Bash read LINE vs read -n LINE

Tags: bash, shell

If I do a while read LINE loop in bash, reading large input from stdin is very inefficient because it does no buffering at all.

Will using while read -n 4096 LINE provide makeshift buffering allowing bash to perform reads of large input more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can verify that reads are performed one at a time with:

```
echo foo | strace bash -c 'read -n 100 f'
```

and see that the single read requires 4 system calls.  But it is easy to accomplish what you want.  To put up to 4096 bytes from stdin into a variable, use process substitution:

```
bash -c 'r=$( dd bs=4096 count=1 2> /dev/null); echo "$r"'
```

Comment: Those reads limit processing drastically, to read a half a gig text file with read LINE is a 5 min process, and I have a 70GB text file. I will try this technique with a large buffer such as 1mb

Comment: Actually the vast majority of that overhead is in the repeated evaluation of simple commands. Bash has an unusually high overhead for evaluating commands - particularly simple commands. That's understandable considering all the steps involved, but other shells tend to optimize more. Anything that requires a tight loop executing any builtin repeatedly pays a huge penalty for using Bash. If you can get away with using `mapfile`, it's a massive improvement simply due to taking out the loop. Compound commands are also much faster in general (like `(())`).

Answer (score 1):

The `-N` (instead of `-n`) option will read past a newline character.

Comment: Yep `-N` is nice. Almost always more useful than `-n` IMO. Sadly it's much newer in Bash.